# How can I print a json string?

Tags: java, json, string, printing

I'm doing a school project (newbie alert) where I need to use the zomato's website to get a cuisine's ID and name depending on the ID I send. This is the code in the demo file:

```
WebServiceConnection web = new WebServiceConnection("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
AcessoDados acesso = new AcessoDados("https://api.zomato.com/v1/cuisines.json", web);
String aces = acesso.getCuisines(310);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
System.out.println(obj.get(aces));
```

All the methods called here were made by our teacher.

WebServiceConnection and AcessoDados function get the link to Zomato's API and the user key. (Zomato API requires a key to work)

"acesso.getCuisines(310)" sends the the value "310", and the method "getCuisines" should return a json string with all the establishments it can find in their website (310 is the ID for Porto, Portugal).

However, it only prints "[]" in the output (without the quotes). It should print something like this:

```
[
{"cuisine_name":"African","cuisine_id":152},
{"cuisine_name":"American","cuisine_id":1},
{"cuisine_name":"Angolan","cuisine_id":951},
{"cuisine_name":"Cafe","cuisine_id":30},
(...)
]
```

I can't find what the problem is or if I'm making any obvious mistake. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you already have a `String`, why not just print that? Am I missing something? Are you really trying to *parse* the string, or to *print* it?

Comment: If I try to print the string "aces", it will just print "[]" anyway. I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific @DanGetz . What I want to do is to print the json string that getCuisine returns.

Comment: Right, but if the string doesn't contain what you want it to, then it's not a problem with printing, it's a problem with the API, or the classes you use to access the API, or how you're using them.

Comment: The JSON object is empty. You need to pass in an argument when you initialize it. Try `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(aces);`

Comment: @user3814613 though it's an array, not a JSON object, so (depending on the JSON library used, I guess?) that probably would still not work right.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Yeah, I also think I am missing something and am not using the methods correctly.  But this is also the first time I am dealing with a json string, and wasn't sure if there was something I should do to print it properly. This thread main objective is to make sure if I'm not making any obvious mistake in the demo mainjava file. Also, thanks for the warning about the key, my brain is so burned out that I'm not even paying attention to the small details lol

Comment: @user3814613 thanks for the suggestion, will try it

Comment: It's as @DanGetz suspected, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If `System.out.println(aces);` prints `[]`, then Zomato's API is returning an empty response, which means that `310` is not a valid `id`. But, if `aces` prints a non-empty string and is a JSON String then the following solution should work.

You are not parsing the JSON string which was received by Zomato API. Instead, you are creating a new `JSONObject` which is empty.

Try doing the following :

```
JSONObject obj = null;
try {
    obj = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parseWithException(aces);
    System.out.println(obj);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Assumptions :

- You are using [json-simple](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried it and I get this error _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject_

Comment: updated the answer. Replace `JSONObject` with `JSONArray` and try again.

Comment: Thank you again. It printed "[]" again. I'm more and more convinced the problem must be in the API itself. I'm going to talk with my colleagues and see if they managed to print it properly. Sorry for wasting your time